# Increase dynamo output by increasing voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am trying to build a device that converts the output of a standard 3W AC bicycle hub dynamo to a 5V DC USB port. My goal is to maximise the power output, efficiency is secondary.

A lot of information about this topic online suggests that a bicycle dynamo behaves more or less as a constant current source. This means that when the resistance of the attached device is high, the dynamo outputs a high voltage, while the current is almost the same as with a low-resistance device. This means that the power output is higher with a high-resistance device, and [some articles](http://pilom.com/BicycleElectronics/DynamoCircuits.htm#Multi) suggest that they have managed to get as much as 11 W out of a simple 3 W dynamo (in this case by putting several LEDs in a row).

My question is first of all, is this true? And if so, how can I make use of this fact to produce a high-current 5 V output?

As far as I understand, I basically need a voltage converter that makes the dynamo create a high voltage (by having a high internal resistance) and then converts this into a high-current 5 V output. So far I have been experimenting with regulating the voltage using a simple DC/DC converter, a Zener diode, and a buck converter. With the first two, I don’t think anything can be done about their internal resistance. About buck converters I don’t have a lot of knowledge about how they work. Are there differences between buck converters regarding their internal resistance, and how can I find one with a high one?

Comment: Sounds like you need a maximum power-point tracking converter.

Comment: exactly... MPPT matches the impedance of the source to the SMPS input impedance while at same time regulating output voltage. This can be done simply by performing a load test for Voc and Isc for RPM speed range of interest. Then plot this. Then using approx 80% of Voc which is proportional to RPM adjust MPT load to match impedance. for max power transfer.

Comment: That all sounds really complicated and expensive?

Comment: So i guess I need a buck converter with a high input impedance? I looked through some buck converters that I could find, but no information about their impedance seems to be written in their data sheet. How can I find a buck converter with a high impedance?

Comment: @cdauth impedance = voltage / current

Comment: I think this paper can answer your problem: [Electronic Power Management for Bicycles](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/14850/BikeLight.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @dmitrygubin